# Sharing vimrc options in different computers

Tags: vimrc

Can I easily keep my vimrc files consistent across multiple computers?

I have different  computers (laptop, desktop home and desktop work) and I want
to keep my Vim configuration consistent, including plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of tools provide solutions to keep your *dotfiles* (that is what your .vimrc is, a dotfile) up to date. Personally I use [homeshick](https://github.com/andsens/homeshick) for this task. From its README.md:

> By the power of git, homeshick enables you to bring the symphony of settings you have poured your heart into with you to remote computers

Homeshick uses Git, so your *dotfiles* are also under version control. Below a comphrensive outline how to work with `homeshick`:

```
# Generate a `castle` named 'dotfiles'.
user@local $ homeshick generate dotfiles
user@local $ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/dotfiles.git
user@local $ git track dotfiles ~/.vimrc
user@local $ git commit -m "Initial commit."
user@local $ git push origin master
```

On an other machine you can also install `homeshick` and clone your dotfiles:

```
user@remote $ homeshick clone username/dotfiles
```

Now you've `dotfiles` on your remote machine.

When you've edited a tracked `dotfile` you can commit it.

```
user@local $ homeshick cd dotfiles
user@local $ git add . && git commit -m "Update something."
user@local $ git push origin master
```

Update your remote machines:

```
user@remote $ homeshick refresh dotfiles
```

Here a link to [my dotfiles](https://github.com/OrangeTux/dotfiles/).

**Bonus** Add `homeshick refresh dotfiles` to your `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` and your dotfiles are always up to date.

Comment: Does this work with direcotires as well (like .vim/bundle/) for plugins?

Comment: Yes, it does. Although I recommend a plugin manager to manage your plugins.